# What is the path to an installed ClickOnce application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, clickonce

I wrote a ["Hallo world" type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in C# to test authentication issues. I'm going to be running the eventual application from a server periodically, so I want to be sure I can get to the resources, and fix that before committing to the whole application.

So, in Visual Studio 2010, I choose Publish....

It says "Where?", and I specify a folder on a shared file system.

It says "How will your users install", and I say, "URL" or something like that.

It says "Where", and I give it a URL in the same shared file system, different folder.

All is right with the world....

Now, I install it on my server by double-clicking "setup" on the shared file system where I published the application.

Now, I find a shortcut in my start menu, all good.

Now, I want to set it up so SQL Server Agent executes it periodically (and tests authentication...) so, what is the URL I give it to execute? I've been trying everything, but not going so well. I don't understand the publish method much at all....

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You had me until you mentioned SQL Server Agent.  What does that have to do with your Publish?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous but I interpreted it as wanting to know the path to the executable for a ClickOnce application. If I'm wrong please clarify the question and the title.

Comment: Igby is right. I just need to find the executable for this click-once app. (I don't know what a click-once app is, but I assume it is related to 'finding the latest version' rather than executing a 'stale' version.) Anyway, I did go, as Igby suggested, to the start menu, clicked properties, and copied the path. Didn't seem to work, but I'll try it again just in case.

Comment: About SQL-Server Agent...the app implements a fairly simple workflow, looking for .xlsx documents posted on a sharepoint document library, then validating them and sending out appropriate emails or loading the contents of the .xlsx into a SQL Server table. It'll run every half hour on days when it expects to find new .xlsx deposits so as to avoid the submitter calling and having the program executed. It would be far more reasonable for it to be a SP workflow, but my client doesn't allow custom actions. I have to use SP Web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Start menu shortcut for your installed application and you'll see that it points to a "ClickOnce Application Reference" (.appref-ms) file buried deep within your user folder. You can start the application by executing that file.

Example:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Igby\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms");
```

I don't know anything about SQL Server Agent, but try giving it this path.

Comment: So, I used Igby's advice and found the start menu shortcut. It didn't work, saying it was not a Win32 executable file. So, I got a brilliant idea. I executed the code, leaving it open, and then used Task Manager to find the folder where the .exe resides, and used that in SQL Server Agent. Remember, my goal was to test authentication. Well, I got another error, but it was an unhandled exception from my C# program, so I think (haven't investigated yet...) I've begun actually testing for authentication issues (Agent uses "sqlagent" to run the process.) Thanks, Igby!