# How do I detect an application was installed via ClickOnce, using WiX?

Tags: wix, clickonce, windows-installer

I'm writing a WiX installer for an application which was deployed previously using ClickOnce.

I would like to detect if the application was installed on the client computer and abort the MSI installation. I searched similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

If I can find a path or some registry key that tells me where the application was installed, I can abort the MSI installation via a Condition.

Using the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436888/what-is-the-path-to-an-installed-clickonce-application), I was able to get somewhere. The ClickOnce shortcuts are files with the **.appref-ms** extension. This is the code I use:

```
<Property Id="APP_CLICKONCE_INSTALLED">
    <DirectorySearch Id="dirSearch.APP.CLICKONCE" AssignToProperty="yes" Path="[StartMenuFolder]" Depth="2">
    <FileSearch Id="fileSearch.APP.CLICKONCE" Name="APP.appref-ms" />
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<Condition Message="App is already installed. Please uninstall it then re-run this setup.">
    <![CDATA[APP_CLICKONCE_INSTALLED = "" OR INSTALLED]]>
</Condition>
```

However, **StartMenuFolder** gives the location for **AllUsers** profile, whereas the click once application is installed for the current user. I am still digging.

Using **perUser** installation the **StartMenuFolder** gives the current user location (I was using **perMachine**):

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" />
```

All is good now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about WiX, but another way to tell if a ClickOnce application is installed is to iterate through the uninstall strings in the registry, which are here:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

You'll want to search for one where the product name of your application matches the Display Name for that set of keys.

Comment: You are right, ClickOnce installers insert an entry in the Uninstall location (as any other Windows installer). The keys are different, but I can rely on DisplayName to find my application.